# Using the HTML 'label' tag with radio buttons

Tags: html, accessibility, forms

Does the `label` tag work with radio buttons?  If so, how do you use it?  I have a form that displays like this:

```
First Name: (text field)
Hair Color: (color drop-down)
Description: (text area)
Salutation: (radio buttons for Mr., Mrs., Miss)
```

I'd like to use the `label` tag for each label in the left column to define its connection to the appropriate control in the right column.  But If I use a radio button, the spec seems to indicate that suddenly the actual "Salutation" label for the form control no longer belongs in the `label` tag, but rather the options "Mr., Mrs., etc." go in the `label` tag.

I've always been a fan of accessibility and the semantic web, but this design doesn't make sense to me.  The `label` tag explicitly declares labels.  The `option` tag selection options.  How do you declare a `label` on the actual label for a set of radio buttons?

**UPDATE:**
Here is an example with code:

```
<tr><th><label for"sc">Status:</label></th>
    <td>&#160;</td>
    <td><select name="statusCode" id="sc">
            <option value="ON_TIME">On Time</option>
            <option value="LATE">Late</option>
        </select></td></tr>
```

This works great.  But unlike other form controls, radio buttons have a separate field for each value:

```
<tr><th align="right"><label for="???">Activity:</label></th>
    <td>&#160;</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="radio" name="es" value="" id="es0" /> Active &#160;
        <input type="radio" name="es" value="ON_TIME" checked="checked" id="es1" /> Completed on Time &#160;
        <input type="radio" name="es" value="LATE" id="es2" /> Completed Late &#160;
        <input type="radio" name="es" value="CANCELED" id="es3" /> Canceled</td>
</tr>
```

What to do?

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080416/labels-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/13089674#13089674

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Does the label tag work with radio buttons?

Yes

> If so, how do you use it?

Same way as for any other form control.

You either give it a `for` attribute that matches the `id` of the control, or you put the control inside the label element.

> I'd like to use the label tag for each label in the left column

A label is for **a** control, not a set of controls.

If you want to caption a set of controls, use a `<fieldset>` with a `<legend>` (and give a `<label>` to each control in the set).

```
<fieldset>
  <legend> Salutation </legend>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="salutation" value="Mr."> Mr. </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="salutation" value="Mrs."> Mrs. </label>
  <!-- etc -->
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Fieldset changes the display on some browsers, no?  Also the "legend" and radio buttons are in different table cells in my case.

Comment: Also, a group of radio buttons with the same name attribute are effectively one control.  Each `<input type="radio"` is a possible value for that control, not the name for the control itself.  I have some code that does the right thing with every other kind of form control I have encountered.  Maybe fieldset is my answer?  Ultimately I guess the point of all this is accessibility for people with limited sight.  Search engines gave up on the "semantic web" from almost day one.

Comment: @GlenPeterson: “a group of radio buttons with the same name attribute are effectively one control” — nope, it’s not. They’re linked, sure, but each button is a control. A `<select>` tag is one control. You could use that instead of radio buttons.

Comment: I updated Quentin's answer. While `<label><input>text<label>` is *technically* valid, it is not a best practice and hasn't been since 03ish. Some AT also has issues with this method. @GlenPeterson not supplying a name to a group of radios, make them work and look like a radio group of 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213253/470749 was a helpful reminder for me about removing `for`.

Answer (score 28):

Ah yes. Here’s how it works.

`<label>` labels *individual fields*, hence each `<input type="radio">` gets its own `<label>`.

To label a *group* of fields (e.g. several radio buttons that share the same `name`), you use a `<fieldset>` tag with a `<legend>` element.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Salutation</legend>

    <label for="salutation_mr">Mr <input id="salutation_mr" name="salutation" type="radio" value="mr"><label>

    <label for="salutation_mrs">Mrs <input id="salutation_mrs" name="salutation" type="radio" value="mrs"><label>

    <label for="salutation_miss">Miss <input id="salutation_miss" name="salutation" type="radio" value="miss"><label>

    <label for="salutation_ms">Ms <input id="salutation_miss" name="salutation" type="radio" value="ms"><label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: +1 for answering the specific question and for "harder to style consistently across browsers" even though Quentin might have stolen some of your thunder.  The issue with this approach is that I don't think it will work across table cells, especially if the table contains other form elements that are not part of the options for this particular set of radio buttons.

Comment: @GlenPeterson: indeed. If you want your labels in one cell and your form fields in another, the HTML above doesn’t work. Arguably, that’s a reason to not use tables to lay out forms.

Comment: Can you link to a way you would recommend to lay out forms for cross browser compatibility on a variety of screen sizes?  Right now we have the field name in the left column, field in the middle, and help text (when appropriate) on the right.

Comment: @GlenPeterson: nothing springs to mind for a recommended way to lay out forms. It depends on the form, and what you’re trying to achieve. One thing I personally like is field labels above the field, as then when you select the field on an iPhone you can still see the label after the browser’s zoomed in on the field.

Comment: You should be able to omit the `for` and `id` attributes here since you're wrapping the inputs in `label`

Comment: @AdamFraser: true, you should, although I believe in the past some screen readers didn’t support that very well. One would hope things have improved, but I haven’t tried it recently.

Comment: Seven years later and it is disappointing that the fieldset method is still not practical because fieldset does not play well with flexbox. div role="radiogroup" makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `aria-role="radiogroup"` to associate the controls without using a `<fieldset>`. This is [one of the techniques suggested by WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA17.html).

```
<div role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="profession_label" aria-describedby="profession_help">
  <p id="profession_label">What is your profession?</p>
  <p id="profession_help">If dual-classed, selected your highest leveled class</p>
  <label><input name="profession" type="radio" value="fighter"> Fighter</label>
  <label><input name="profession" type="radio" value="mage"> Mage</label>
  <label><input name="profession" type="radio" value="cleric"> Cleric</label>
  <label><input name="profession" type="radio" value="theif"> Thief</label>
</div>
```

However, I noticed that using this technique the WebAim Wave tool to give a warning about a missing `<fieldset>`, so I'm not sure what AT support for this is like.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a label for a set of buttons, but for each button.
In this case, the labels are "Mr.", "Mrs." and "Miss", not "Salutation".

**UPDATE** 
Maybe you should just use another tag for this "label" of yours - since it's not really a label.

```
<tr>
    <th align="right" scope="row"><span class="label">Activity:</span></th>
    <td>&#160;</td>
    <td align="left"><label><input type="radio" name="es" value="" id="es0" /> Active &#160;</label>
    [... and so on]
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "Maybe you should just use another tag for this "label" of yours - since it's not really a label."?

Comment: It isn't really linked to any available option, even if it defines a set of options' name.

Comment: What other tag I should use?  Did you mean I should make one up?

Answer (score 2):

my 2 cents to the topic, or rather a side node *(it does not use implicit association to be able to be placed anywhere, but linking)*:
**grouping** is done by the `name` attribute, and **linking** by the `id` attribute:

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="faqList" id="faqListItem1" checked />
        <div>
            <label for="faqListItem1">i 1</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="faqList" id="faqListItem2" />
        <div>
            <label for="faqListItem2">i 2</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="faqList" id="faqListItem3" />
        <div>
            <label for="faqListItem3">i 3</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is the approach that I've taken in the past; whether it is considered a best practice, idk, but it is consistent with how radio buttons are grouped so seems very natural to me. Unfortunately, the defs for label have the label's for attribute associated with an id, not name. So, this approach generates warnings.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: no, you can't connect Salutation to one of the radio buttons. It wouldn't make sense that if you'd click on Salutation, one of the options would be selected. Instead, you can give Mr, Mrs and Miss their own labels, so if someone clicks on one of those words, the corresponding radio button will be selected.

```
<input id="salutation_mr" type="radio" value="mr" name="salutation">
<label for="salutation_mr">Mr.</label>
<input id="salutation_mrs" type="radio" value="mrs" name="salutation">
<label for="salutation_mrs">Mrs.</label>
<input id="salutation_miss" type="radio" value="miss" name="salutation">
<label for="salutation_miss">Miss</label>
```

<del>I do think that you could still wrap Salutation inside a `<label>` element, you just can't use the `for` attribute.</del> I stand corrected, see the comments below. Although it's technically possible, it's not what `<label>` was meant for.

Comment: “no, you can't connect Salutation to the radio buttons” — incorrect. `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` are designed for this purpose.

Comment: I like the idea of using a label without associating it - it shows effort to do the right thing.  But I suspect the browser would just ignore it without knowing what to associate it with.  It might even expose a bug in some browser somewhere that wouldn't have happened without the dangling label tag.

Comment: @GlenPeterson: “I like the idea of using a label without associating it - it shows effort to do the right thing.” I guess, although it also shows that the person in question hasn’t looked up [what `<label>` is actually for](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-label-element.html#the-label-element).

Comment: Oops, sorry Nic — when I said “the person in question” I hadn’t actually noticed that you’d suggested using label without `for`, I just though @GlenPeterson was talking hypothetically. No offence meant.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, none taken! You were actually right, I hadn't looked it up and I use `<label>` for this purpose myself too. Learning new things every day ;) thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: @NicNLD: phew! I would have been a bit more direct and polite if I’d noticed your suggestion. Glad the link was helpful. Most HTML tags aren’t restricted in their use like `<label>` is, so I’ve seen lots of people use `<label>` more generally.

Answer (score 0):

The Label's 'for' attribute corresponds to the Radio buttons ID. So...

```
<label for="thisRad">Radio Button 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="thisRad" />
```

Hope it helps.

You'd want yours to look something like this...

```
Salutation<br />
<label for="radMr">Mr.</label><input type="radio" id="radMr" />
<label for="radMrs">Mrs.</label><input type="radio" id="radMrs" />
<label for="radMiss">Miss.</label><input type="radio" id="radMiss" />
```

Comment: You can also wrap the radio element in a label, if you don't want to use an id.

Comment: I don’t think you’re quite answering the OP’s actual question. If I understand correctly, he’s asking how to mark up a label that applies to an entire set of radio buttons.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I read it again, you seem to be right lol. My bad.