# Error validation for a radio button in HTML

Tags: html, validation, label

I'm going through the process of validating my HTML using W3 validator when it checks through my pages I get a validation error:

> The label element may contain at most one button, input, keygen,
>   meter, output, progress, select, or textarea descendant. From line
>   136, column 33; to line 136, column 76
>                 2 Ratin

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong because as far as I can tell I have only used one input type in the label.

Here is my Code for that segment:

```
<label> Rating
  <br>

  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"> 1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"> 2
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"> 3
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"> 4
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"> 5
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="6"> 6
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="7"> 7
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="8"> 8
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="9"> 9
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="10"> 10
  <br>

</label>
```

The webpage does work either way, i would just like to fix the validation if possible.

Here is the code for my entire page if it is needed:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contact</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Slideshow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/page.css">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

          <h1> Nathan Rivera </h1>

          <h1> Portfolio </h1>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <script>
      function checkforblank() {

        if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
          alert("Entry can't be empty");
          document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "red";
          return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('email').value == "") {
          alert("Entry can't be empty");
          document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
          return false;
        }




        var radios = document.getElementsByName("rating");
        var formValid = false;

        var i = 0;
        while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
          if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true; {
            i++;
          }
        }

        if (!formValid) {
          alert("Please Pick Rating");
          return formValid;
          document.getElementsByName("rating").style.borderColor = "red";
        }

      }

    </script>


  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row" id="inner">

        <div class="col-lg-12 center">

          <ul class="nav nav-pills">

            <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>

            <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>

            <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>

            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>

            <li class="active"><a href="Survey.html">Survey</a></li>

          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

          <form method="post" action "#" onSubmit="return checkforblank()">

            <fieldset>

              <label> Name:
                <br>

                <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

              </label>

              <br>
              <br>

              <label> Email:
                <br>

                <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

              </label>


              <br>
              <br>

              <label> Rating
                <br>

                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"> 1
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"> 2
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"> 3
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"> 4
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"> 5
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="6"> 6
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="7"> 7
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="8"> 8
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="9"> 9
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="10"> 10
                <br>

              </label>

              <br>
              <br>

              <div class="form-group">

                <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comments"></textarea>

              </div>

            </fieldset>

          </form>

          <form action="javascript:alert('Thank You For Your Input')" method="get" onSubmit="return checkforblank()">

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

          </form>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    </div>


    <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Jquery/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Quick question.... Why are you using JS for this when you can do it way easier with jQuery?

Comment: Because I havent figured out how to use jquerry yet. JavaScript in general is really confusing for me.

Comment: Include a jQuery file into your project and you can get element like this for instance: if($('email').val()=="")... This way you can write much more cleaner and efficient code... :)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I just learned how to use bootstrap as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many errors in your code.

First, you have `<div>` and `<h1>` elements in `<head>`. You can't do that.

Then there are `<br>` tags in your `<label>`, this is also not allowed.

Then in your form call you have `action"#"`while it should be `action="#"`

And lastly there is one extra closing `</div>` at the end.

So your code should look something like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contact</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Slideshow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/page.css">

    <script>
      function checkforblank() {

        if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
          alert("Entry can't be empty");
          document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "red";
          return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('email').value == "") {
          alert("Entry can't be empty");
          document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
          return false;
        }




        var radios = document.getElementsByName("rating");
        var formValid = false;

        var i = 0;
        while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
          if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true; {
            i++;
          }
        }

        if (!formValid) {
          alert("Please Pick Rating");
          return formValid;
          document.getElementsByName("rating").style.borderColor = "red";
        }

      }

    </script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

          <h1> Nathan Rivera </h1>

          <h1> Portfolio </h1>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row" id="inner">

        <div class="col-lg-12 center">

          <ul class="nav nav-pills">

            <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>

            <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>

            <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>

            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>

            <li class="active"><a href="Survey.html">Survey</a></li>

          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

          <form method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return checkforblank()">

            <fieldset>

              <label for="name"> Name: </label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
              <br>
              <br>

              <label for="email"> Email: </label>
              <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
              <br>
              <br>

              <label> Rating </label> <br>

              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"> 1
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"> 2
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"> 3
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"> 4
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"> 5
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="6"> 6
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="7"> 7
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="8"> 8
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="9"> 9
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" value="10"> 10
              <br>
              <br>

              <div class="form-group">

                <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comments"></textarea>

              </div>

            </fieldset>

          </form>

          <form action="javascript:alert('Thank You For Your Input')" method="get" onSubmit="return checkforblank()">

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

          </form>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Jquery/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

If you check it in validator you'll see that there are no errors.

And, in future, please double check your code before posting questions here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm rather new to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are for one input, you are using one on 10 inputs.
This is a great example of how you might achieve what you are going for:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend> Rating </legend>
   <label> <input type="radio" value="1" name="rating"> 1 </label>
   <label> <input type="radio" value="2" name="rating"> 2 </label>
   <!-- etc -->
 </fieldset>
```

This was adapted from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273806/using-the-html-label-tag-with-radio-buttons).
For more data on working `fieldsets` check out [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)