# Thymeleaf fragments with parameterized input not working

Tags: java, servlets, thymeleaf

Fragment

```html
    <div th:fragment="sort (label,field)">
        <label th:text="${label}"> Label
            <input th:name="'sort-' + ${field}" type="radio" value="asc"/>
            <input th:name="'sort-' + ${field}" type="radio" value="dsc"/>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Usage

```html
    <div th:replace="fragments/form.html :: sort(label = 'Name', field = 'name')"></div>
```

What appears on the page

```html
    <label>Name</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't place your `<input>` elements inside the `<label>` element.

When you use `th:text="${label}"` in your `<label>` element, the results of that Thymeleaf expression replace *everything* inside the `<label>...</label>` tags - including the nested `<input>` elements. That is why you only see `<label>Name</label>`.

A label is more typically associated with an input element (or group of elements) using the `for` attribute. You can read more about that in this question:

[Using the HTML 'label' tag with radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273806/using-the-html-label-tag-with-radio-buttons)