# How can I remove an HTML element that has the data type string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, removechild, insertadjacenthtml

I am trying to **redesign a quiz template** that only allows users to choose one answer before the other options are disabled. The user should be able to choose another answer (erasing the first) before submitting.

I can remove the highlighted color class if a new answer is chosen:

```
answer.classList.remove("correct");
```

How do I remove the element for the 'tick' icon:

```
let tickIconTag = '<div class="icon tick"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>';
```

from this parent element:

```
'<div class="option"><span>'+  multiple_choice_option[i] +'</span></div>'
```

when the option is set like this:

```
  const option = option_list.querySelectorAll(".option");
  for(i=0; i < option.length; i++)
  {
    option[i].setAttribute("onclick", "optionSelected(this);");
  }//end for
```

and the tickIconTag is added like this:

```
answer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",tickIconTag);
```

I have tried multiple ways but the main issue is that:

1.Using answer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", blankelement) shifts tick inward not removed

2.Using tickIconTag.remove() gives the error "tickIconTag.remove is not a function"

3.Using answer.removeChild(tickIconTag) give the error "Parameter 1 is not of type node".

How can I set precisely the same element to blank and not shift it or remove it?

This is an image of what happens when I try to replace the element with a blank one.
[Green tick shifted but not removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEjXH.png)

Comment: `<input type="radio">` is your friend, don't neglect it.

Comment: where would I use this?

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72259323/2813224)

Answer (score 0):

### Pure CSS Solution

> *"...only allows users to choose one answer before the other options are disabled. The user should be able to choose another answer (erasing the first) before submitting."*

That's the exact behavior of a [RadioGroupList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio). Click each circle in **Figure I**.

**Figure I**

```html
<input id='a1' name='A1' type='radio'><br>
<input id='b1' name='A1' type='radio'><br>
<input id='c1' name='A1' type='radio'><br>
<input id='d1' name='A1' type='radio'><br>
```

Notice the `name` of each element is the same `A1`. This allows the group of radio buttons to have [mutual exclusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button#:%7E:text=Each%20radio%20button%20is%20normally,only%20one%20can%20be%20selected.).

With a [`<label>` associated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273806/using-the-html-label-tag-with-radio-buttons) with each radio button, and some CSS we can recreate what is in the OP without JavaScript. `<label>`s have a unique feature in which they can be associated with a [form control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content) by assigning the `for` attribute with the value of a form control's #id. Once associated a `<label>` is insync with said form control so that if the `<label>` was clicked, so to does the form control as long as both are on the same page. See **Figure II**.

**Figure II**

```css
input {
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;
}

label {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: block;
}

input:checked+label {
  color: gold;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<input id='fc' type='checkbox'>
<label for='fc'>CLICK HERE</label>
```

In the CSS the following ruleset allowed the `<label>` to change whenever the checkbox was checked:

**Figure III**

```css
input:checked+label {
  color: gold;
  background: blue;
}
```

In **Figure IV** each `<label>` is associated to a hidden radio button. The user will only see and interact with the `<label>`. Also, the example in **Figure IV** is responsive.

**Figure IV**

```css
html {
  font: 300 3vmax/1.2 'Segoe UI';
}

input {
  display: none
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70vw;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 0.05rem solid cyan;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: inherit;
  background: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label b {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.far {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: lightblue;
}

input:checked+label {
  border-color: green;
  background: lightgreen;
}

input:checked+label i {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<input id='a1' name='A1' type='radio' value='a' required><label for='a1'><b>Text for</b><i class="far fa-circle-check"></i></label>
<input id='b1' name='A1' type='radio' value='b'><label for='b1'><b>each answer</b><i class="far fa-circle-check"></i></label>
<input id='c1' name='A1' type='radio' value='c'><label for='c1'><b>goes into</b><i class="far fa-circle-check"></i></label>
<input id='d1' name='A1' type='radio' value='d'><label for='d1'><b>a label</b><i class="far fa-circle-check"></i></label>
```