# Twitter Bootstrap form Accesibility - Inline checkboxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

I am building a large form with Bootstrap and am trying to make it as accessible as possible. It needs the site to be WCAG2AA compliant.

Is there a way of laying out the mark-up for a group of inline check-boxes without having the input nested inside the label or will I just have to modify the style-sheets to suit my needs.

Also Are there any useful guides or links out there on making Bootstrap more accessible?

Cheers,

Brian

Comment: `input` inside a `label` isn't an accessibility problem by itself. The lack of `for/id` attributes to associate them would be the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a few questions about checkboxes and radio buttons in the past week or so. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080416/labels-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/13089674#comment18155680_13089674) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273806/using-the-html-label-tag-with-radio-buttons). Check these out to see if they assist any.

> Is there a way of laying out the mark-up for a group of inline check-boxes without having the input nested inside the label or will I just have to modify the style-sheets to suit my needs.

To me it sounds like you are thinking of doing `<label><input> text</label>`. Is this correct? Some assistive technologies have issues with this if I recall correctly, and it fell out of a *best practice* years ago. I advise you to to follow how I outlined it in my answer in the linked question.

Comment: Hi there, sorry perhaps I didn't explain myself properly. I was hoping to stay clear of nesting the input inside the label and hoped to structure the mark-up like the following: `<fieldset> <legend>Select your pizza toppings:</legend> <input id="ham" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="ham" /><label for="ham">Ham</label></fieldset>` However Bootstraps Stylesheets don't seem to cater for this.

Comment: What does the bootstrap do? The only thing that pops up is it doesn't look pretty.